# Alter table structure without erasing data

Tags: django, django-models

Am new to django, and i would like to add a column to a table without erasing data in the database. The command

```
python manage.py reset polls
```

erases data in the entire database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to add a new model, you can use `manage.py syncdb` for that. Unfortunately, if you've changed a model, the default Django commands can't do that for you.

In order to change your model with your existing data, you're going to have to tell Django and the database how to migrate your data from the old table to the new.

Answer (score 3):

I make this kind of changes like this:

Change model with new column.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(maxlength=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    newColumn = models.DateField()
```

Show new create table command: **python manage.py sqlall**

```
blah blah
CREATE TABLE "books_book" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "publisher_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "books_publisher" ("id"),
    "newColumn" date NOT NULL
);
```

I change by hand the table in database:

```
mysql -u xxx -p dbxxx
alter table ttttt add column "newColumn" date NULL;   (*1)
```

(*1) Should by Null or you must to inform a default value

Remember to create indexes and other constraints if it is needed.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to danihp answer if you have big project you can use

```
python manage.py sql <app_name>
```

So in your case:

```
python manage.py sql polls
```

That way you get only "polls" sql clause.